# Inconsistent results of an ajax query to a table

Tags: php, ajax

N.B. - sorry for the wrong title initially - that was a different question for which I'm trying to solve without posting.

I'd like to ask you two simple questions about returning data from a php file call.
Thanks to this forum, I'm pretty confident about writing PHP code amongst HMTL to save data to a db table, and to retrieve data from a table.

But now, on a single page, I need to ***add*** data to a table, ***retrieve*** data from a table, and ***update*** that data, all without a refresh of the HTML screen. So I made a little "test" environment with a ***MySQL table*** (6 fields), a "***backend***" written in pure php, and a "***frontend***" written in HTML and JavaScript.

All day yesterday I was pulling out what little hair I have left, but finally figured out the concept of passing data back from a php file to the html/javascript file (I'll give you all the code below).
The whole thing works GREAT! ***But it is not consistent*** - so an experiment was performed with these steps:

- ftp upload of frontend
- ftp upload of backend
- refresh frontend 2x on IE
- Enter the number "150" in the input box. ("150" is the row number
  for Jimi Hendrix :-) )
- Click the "submit" button on the form. (In    this experiment I never
  used the "enter" key)
- If it works, an alert pops up with Jimi Hendrix written in it.
- If it doesn't work - nothing pops up.

So here are the results of two experiments Y=Jimi Hendrix N=no popup box

- refresh
- Y N Y N N Y Y N Y Y Y N Y Y N Y Y Y N N Y N Y N Y
- refresh
- Y Y Y N Y Y N Y Y Y Y N Y N Y Y N Y N Y N N Y Y N

I really cant see a pattern here about when the routines "work".
I've seen this behavior is some of my other code regarding saving to a db.

Now my two questions:

- Can you explain the variability in how this code works? Any way I
  might fix it?
- I've got Jimi Hendrix in an "alert" box, but what command would you use to put him in a div?
  ?.load? or some other command?

Here's the PHP file:

```
<?php
$localid = $_POST['localid'];

$host = "hostname";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}

$query = " select * from testtable where localid = $localid ";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("could not query database 1");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $firstname = $row['firstname'];
 $lastname = $row['lastname'];
 $zip = $row['physzip'];
 $gender = $row['gender'];
 $dob = $row['dob'];
}

$variablestopass = array
(
    'ln' => $lastname,
    'fn' => $firstname,
    'zip' => $zip,
    'gender' => $gender,
    'dob' => $dob 
);
echo json_encode($variablestopass);                     
?>
```

And here is the "frontend" (without the header):

```
<body>
<form name="#inputform">
<table class="divtest">
<tr><td>Localid:</td><td> <input type="text" id="localid"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<div id="loadmehere" class="divtest"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$("#submitbutton").click(function() {

var localid = document.getElementById("localid").value;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testajaxbackend.php",
        data: {localid: localid},
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(result) {
                                   alert(result['fn'] + result['ln'] + result['zip'] + result['gender'] + result['dob']);
                                   },
        error : function() { alert("error"); }
});//End of ajax call
});//End of click
});//End of ready
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I thank you in advance for any help you might render.
PS - I also present this, in case other noobs might be helped by my brute-force code.

Comment: lol I read your return variable as VariableStopAss

Comment: Sidenote - you don't seem to be sanitizing your `$_POST['localid']`. Also, I don't quite understand your retrieval of the $firstname and such. You do a while loop, but next time the loop runs the vars will be overwritten.

Comment: Thought. Add `e.preventDefault();` to the first line of click function. Also of course add e as the input to click. Submit function might be performing defaults unknowingly.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments!
@75inchpianist - You should see some of my OTHER variable names! :-)


Thanks all!

Comment: @Sidenote - I'll have to read about "sanitizing" I'm not sure what that is, but I can find out. In terms of the while loop, there is only one "row" to retrieve (with one "localid" there is only one row) - and I couldn't figure out how to grab the variables without a while loop - It only loops once.

Comment: @Foo_Chow - I'll give that a try - Haven't see those before.

Comment: @TimSPQR basically it will prevent the normal action whatever you append it to. So in this case the clicking of submit will no longer submit, rather execute your ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Ajax, you have to leave the form submition aside. You can't use the both. It will be confuse. When you click on the submit button, the is reloaded and the ajax context will be lost.

Change your button to:

`<input type="button" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" />`

If you prefer, you can remove the `form` tags.

For security, change your PHP to this:

```
<?php
$localid = $_POST['localid'];

if (!is_numeric($localid)) { echo "Error!"; exit; }// Prevention of SQL injection

$host = "hostname";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error(); exit;}

$localid = mysqli_real_escape_string($localid, $cxn); // Double prevention of SQL injection

$query = "SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE localid = $localid LIMIT 0, 1";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("could not query database 1");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $variablestopass = array
    (
        'ln' => $row['lastname'],
        'fn' => $row['firstname'],
        'zip' => $row['physzip'],
        'gender' => $row['gender'],
        'dob' => $row['dob']
    );

    echo json_encode($variablestopass);
}
else 
{
    echo "Erro selection id"; 
}
?>
```

Well, as you can see I've added some SQL injection prevention and a result check with `mysqli_num_rows`. If I understood right, this code might return just one result. So I removed the `while` block and added the `LIMIT` clause on you query. So the front end will be certain that will receive just one result. If I was wrong, you may remove the `LIMIT` clause and set back the `while`, but it have to be this way, cause your way will fail to return more than one record:

```
$variablestopass = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $variablestopass[] = array
    (
        'ln' => $row['lastname'],
        'fn' => $row['firstname'],
        'zip' => $row['physzip'],
        'gender' => $row['gender'],
        'dob' => $row['dob']
    );
}
```

Finally, I'll change a little your `success` on ajax object to this:

```
sucess: function(result)
{
    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

    alert(result.fn + " - " + result.ln + " - " + result.zip); // and so on...
}
```

NOTE: This `success` function spects just one result.

Any doubt, let us know. Good luck!

Comment: Agreed. Using `type="button"` is better than submit. My earlier comment performed a similar effect as switching the type. Definitely good to escape as well, assuming the project will be used by anyone that isnt you. I dont see any reason to remove the `from` tags though.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! and Thank you!
I've spent the last couple of hours on this and have the following results:
1 - changing the button type from "submit" to "button" was genius - it changed EVERYTHING! It now works 100% of the time.

Comment: 2 - The addition of the two lines for injection protection made it crash - wouldn't do anything. I'll bet that it has to do with the fact that the number I submit is really a number and not a string - More homework for me in that regard.
3 - I've never seen that "LIMIT" addition to the query statement and it seems to work very nice.
4 - The query to return the result will always be a single line, but I didn't know how to pull out a single line without doing a WHILE statement - your code works great!

Comment: 5 - I could NOT use the jQuery.parseJSON(result); two lines because I kept getting a jQuery error in line 541:
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character 
jquery-1.9.1.js, line 541 character 4
So I'll have to study that command a bit more.

Comment: So clearly, these were very nice additions to the code - I've learned a lot and will continue to study this.

Again, I wanted to thank all of you for taking the time to help a noob, and also wanted to thank ALL of the experts on the forum for their time and expertise while I cruise around trying to learn something!

Comment: Nice, man! You're welcome! I had to learn those codes some day without no teacher and I know it's hard. But keep going that you're not a noob, you have some skills!

Comment: Thanks - and for others who happen to be snooping around - I figured out how to populate a div field with a variable returned from an ajax call:

<div id="identificationame"></div>
$('#identificationname').html(result['fn']);

And for an form input field:
<input type="text" id="forminputidname" value="">
$('#forminputidname').val(result['fn']);

I added these right at the bottom of the ajax call, and they put Jimi Hendrix first name in a div, and prepopulate an input field.

Again, thanks very much!

Comment: @TimSPQR Just an advice. Make sure you marked as answer all the answers for your questions. People don't like to answer questions that the user with much questions without marked answer, asks. I see you got another question with an answer without marked Blender's answer.